# URL returned from Firebase storage works in one project but not the other

Tags: swift, debugging, url, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm working on a video sharing app, I have an Objective-C version as well as a Swift one. I upload the URL of a chosen video to Firebase storage successfully in both projects as well as retrieve them. In the Objective-C project the video(s) show up fine, no problem, but in the Swift version, although the URL is there logged to the console, exactly the same, they don't, the AVPlayer is just blank, no noise no nothing.

Here is my Swift upload and retrieval code:

Upload: (Tried with both metadata.downloadURL and metadata.downloadURL.absoluteString)

```
func sendData(string: String) {

    if string == "" && self.urlToUpload == nil {

        self.showAlertWithTitle("Please upload a valid file and caption", message: "")

    }

    else {

    //write url to storage ref

    if urlToUpload != nil {

        let childString = NSString(format: "Video %@", NSUUID().UUIDString)

        let videosRef = storageReference.child("postVideos").child(childString as String)

        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "Video"

        let uploadTask = videosRef.putFile(self.urlToUpload!, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("ERROR DESC. %@", error?.localizedDescription)
                print("ERROR %@", error)

            }

            else {
                print(metadata)

                //pop alert here then set button back etc.
            }
        })

        uploadTask.observeStatus(.Success) { snapshot in

            print("Success!")
            print(snapshot)

            print(snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL())

            //self.downloadURLToUpload = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()

            self.downloadURLString = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

            uploadTask.removeAllObservers()

            //if download url exists send rest of data

            let emailString = String(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.email!)

            //let postToSend = Post(name: emailString, message: string, downloadURLString: String(self.downloadURLToUpload!))

            let postToSend = Post(name: emailString, message: string, downloadURLString: self.downloadURLString)

            let postDict = ["name" : postToSend.name!, "message" : postToSend.message!, "downloadURLString" :postToSend.downloadURLString!]

            self.reference.child("messages").childByAutoId().setValue(postDict)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Retrieval:

```
func returnDataFromURL(urlString: String!, completion: CompletionHandler) {

    let strg = FIRStorage.storage()

    let ref = strg.referenceForURL(urlString)

    ref.downloadURLWithCompletion { (url, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

        }
        else {
            completion(url: url!)
        }
    }

}
```

The URLs themselves are the same format but the properties appear a bit different in the console though, this might be my issue when passing them to the AVPlayer (which works with test videos so is not the issue).

How the retrieved download URL prints out in the Objective-C project.

[image]

And in Swift...

[image]

Thank you for the help of course, like always.

Comment: Are you trying to download the same file in two projects (same URL), or do you have two copies of the file? My answer below is if you're trying to do the same URL, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: No, different file, and two different Firebase projects (I should have made that clearer) but i'll check it out anyway. Thanks!

Comment: So the only difference is Swift vs Obj-C? Odd... and you're not getting an error when you try to download it, it's just empty?

Comment: Exactly, and no not at all, it returns a URL in the same fashion but one can play in the AVPlayer and the other (Swift) doesn't. I tested the player with another video too so it's not the problem. The only differences are the ones I posted above when logging to the console.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: this is intended behavior; just download it using an HTTP library (`NSURLSession`, `GTMSessionFetcher`, `AlamoFire`) rather than converting it to a `FIRStorageReference` with `referenceWithURL`.

Long story: You've got an project (let's call it `foo`), that has a storage bucket `foo.appspot.com` attached to it. You upload an object (let's call it `myFile.txt`). Now, you want to share that object with your friends.

There are two ways of representing `myFile.txt` stored in your bucket `foo.appspot.com`:

- Private, internal URL: `gs://foo.appspot.com/myFile.txt`
- Public, external URL: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/foo.appspot.com/o/myFile.txt?alt=media&token=<token>`

The private URL must be downloaded through our library (`dataWithMaxSize:completion:`, `writeToFile:`), and are checked for correct authentication credentials and then run through [Firebase Storage Security Rules](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) for authorization.

The public URL can be downloaded through any library (like `AlamoFire`, etc.) and by any user, whether they're using your app or not. These downloads aren't checked for authentication or authorization, and instead rely on you, the developer, to properly control (we allow you to revoke that unguessable token if a URL gets shared too widely). Since there are occasionally reasons why a developer gives us a public download URL and they want to manipulate it (say to add a new file at the reference or modify the existing one, as well as allow for external downloads), we provide the `referenceWithURL:` method to convert a public URL (`https://`) to a private URL (`gs://`), which can then be manipulated.

Thus, when you try to create a storage reference from a URL outside of your project (which would imply that you will perform an authenticated and authorized request on that file), we throw an exception because there's no way you can stick a download URL like `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bar.appspot.com/o/myOtherFile.txt?alt=media&token=<token>` into an app in project `foo` and get any result other than failure--we don't allow randomly authenticated users from project `foo` to operate on files from project `bar` (beyond the public download URL).

In the future, when we support multiple buckets per project, we'll let you create references to those other buckets that you have control of, but until then, just download the files as you would any other file.